# How do you use textContent.substring() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, substring

I have the following function:

```
function setEventRemove(target) {
target.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    const bookEl = target.parentNode;
    const bookStorage = {
        id: bookEl.querySelector('.id').textContent.substring(4),
        volumeInfo: {
            title: bookEl.querySelector('.titre').textContent.substring(7),
            author: bookEl.querySelector('.author').textContent.substring(8),
            description: bookEl.querySelector('.desc').textContent.substring(12),
            imageLinks: {
                thumbnail: bookEl.querySelector('img').src,
            }
        }
    };
    let arrayBook = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('arrayBook'));
    if(arrayBook == null || arrayBook == '') {
        array = [];
```

But I don't understand what textContent.substring() does.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

substring method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string For example

```
bookEl.querySelector('.titre').textContent.substring(7)
```

the above code is extracting text content from html element with class name title

Scenario 1:

if suppose text content is "Hello World" then substring(2) would extract the character starting from 2nd position to rest of the character and it starts counting from 0 so in this case second position starts from 'l' so it would print
'llo world!'

Scenario 2:

In the above example only starts position was mentioned we can also mention end position like below

substring(0,1) then it will start from 0th character and move upto 1 character so result will be 'H' in "Hello World" string

For more clarification you can visit this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp